# getting the checkboxes values checked-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have check boxes inside a form (id='submit_slides_1'):

After submitting the form I want to fetch all of the values of the checked checkboxes:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='chk_selection_info_box' name='thumb_selection[]' value='" + images[i]['url'] + "'>
```

and in my javascript I have the following code:

```
$("#submit_slides_1").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x=$("#thumb_selection").is(":checked");
    alert(x);
  }
);
```

But it keeps giving  me False; Am I missing something?

ADDED:
Tried but it says "undefined" too:

```
$(".chk_selection_info_box:checked").each(function(i,l)
{
    alert(l.value);
});
```

If you need more clarification, please let me know which part you need more clarification!

Thanks

Comment: show us your full html

Comment: You say the `form` has the `name` of `'submit_slides_1'`, but you're selecting the `form` with the *`id`* of `"#submit_slides_1"`. This is obvious, but not necessarily correct; please: show your HTML, don't describe it at us.

Comment: @David: No thei d is 'submit_slides_1'; my bad! still not working!

Comment: I think what you need is `$('[name="thumb_selection[]"]:checked').map(function(){return this.value});` will return the array of values of the checked check boxes

Comment: [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns a boolean representing whether the condition ***is*** true or false. Move the `:checked` pseudo class to your selector `$('#thumb_selection:checked')`

Comment: If you dont mind could you please your full solution?

Comment: Wow Minus score? I wish I could figure out why I got minus score!?! Weird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no element with that id. That would be what you are missing. Add the id.

BUT your code suggests you have multiple checkboxes, if that is the case, setting an id will not work and using a class would not work since is() will only work off the first element.

```
var checkedElements = $(".chk_selection_info_box:checked");
```

You than would need to use `.serialize()`, `.map()`, or `.each()` to get all the values.

Comment: Using an ID won't work if she wants the checked status from multiple checkboxes.

Comment: thats true: multiple checkboxes: even the following code does not work:

$(".chk_selection_info_box:checked").each(function()
{
    alert($this.val());
});
says this undefined? Why?

Comment: Because there is no `$this`, there is `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

If they all have the `.chk_selection_info_box` class, then select those elements with the `:checked` selector, and `.map()` the values to a collection, and convert it `.toArray()`.

```
var values = $(".chk_selection_info_box:checked").map(function(i, el) {
    return el.value
}).toArray();
```

Comment: You solved my problem; but why my code does not work! I didnt have any cluew about maps!

Comment: @Pasargad: The `is()` method returns a `boolean` value that tells you if the element matches the selector. The `.map()` simply takes the collection, and creates a new collection with the return values of the callback function. So we selected all the boxes that are checked, and returned the `.value` of each box to the new Array.

Comment: It meakes sense ti me now; could you please let me know a solution with each loop as well!
I guess this one should work too, but apparently not:

$("#thumb_selection:checked").each(function()
{
   
    alert($this.val());
});

Comment: I am sorry to let you know your solution just return the very last chechbox selected!

Comment: @Pasargad: No it doesn't. It will return all the values for all the checked checkboxes with that class. Do all your boxes have that class? The code in your comment above will only return one result because you can only have one ID on the page. The answer you accepted uses the same selector I'm using, but I've shown how to get the values.

Answer (score -2):

Try this mate

```
var x = $(".chk_selection_info_box").prop('checked');
```